# Regex to match words separated by white space and/or new line

Tags: regex

I am trying to generate regex for below values. The regex need to match both. Please suggest. The tags can be separated by newline and spaces.

```
<code>  <pre>

<code>  
    <pre>
```

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: @anubhava I tried (<code>)(\s+)(<pre>) ,<code>\s+<pre>. But they are not matching

Comment: Can you show the full text with tags?

Comment: Don't use regex to parse HTML/XML/etc... Use parsers designed for the language in question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<code>\s*<pre>`

`\s` stands for any white space character

`*` means zero or more times

In order to match `<code><pre><code><pre>` with any white space characters between them, you can add `\s*` between the tags, similar to:

```
<code>\s*<pre>\s*<code>\s*<pre>
```

Working example here: https://regex101.com/r/PcFX4a/3

Comment: Its not matching second case. May be because of new line character

Comment: which language are you using? it is supposed to match new lines, as well. You can validate it using this site: https://regex101.com/

Comment: You can see that it does match here: https://regex101.com/r/PcFX4a/1 Perhaps you are trying to match something else? What is your exact input?

Comment: Do you mean that you need to match <code><pre><code><pre>?

Comment: It worked after tweaking to <code>\n\s*<pre>. But don't know the exact reason. Thank you.